My fetched data return as undefined, how do I fix this?
I have this markup and code on my page:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Sidebar.css'
import TagsList from './TagsList';

const Sidebar = () => {
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/tags')
        .then(res=>{
            res.json();
        })
        .then(data =>{
            console.log(data);            
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="side-content">
        <div className="side-cont">
        <div>Search (<a href="#">advanced</a>)</div>
        <input type="text" />
        <div>Hidden posts 0</div>
        <div>
            <TagsList tags={tags} title="Tags" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Sidebar;

For some reason, when I try to fetch my data, the browser returns "undefined". Does anyone have a fix to this? Thank you so much

Maybe because you need to add a return at res.json(); line?

Voted to close for a different reason too quickly, but this is a duplicate: When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions

ooh Imma try it out, thankyou so much

You have to return the res.json.
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/tags')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setTags(data));

The issue is your format of the short-form function; the curly braces create scope and by default JS returns undefined in a function scope. Read more here.

wait so res and response is not the same thing? I am kinda new to react so I dont know yet

It is. The difference is arbitrary. Just be consistent with naming your variables. The issue here though is your format of the short-form function; the curly braces create scope and by default JS returns undefined in a function scope.
